# Python - pptx - Text Reads

Tags: python, python-pptx

Code to import data from table and text frame:

```
 pres = Presentation(ppt_file)

    for slide in pres.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if(shape.has_text_frame):
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        print run.text
```

I've a slide like this:

[image]

Output is:
   **Running text**

Text is being read from the left frame or the big box but not from the two right frames.

Comment: This should be two questions. Check that the two right frames are not group shapes.

Comment: Also check that A and B are actual text and not part of an image.

Comment: @scanny: Yes A and B are text. The images are placed above the text. Merged the two questions as I didn't want to be redundant.

Comment: These are two separate problems. Which one do you want me to address?

Comment: @scanny Problem 2 please

Comment: If you make it a separate question and tag it with 'python-pptx' I'll see it. Make sure you show the code you use and the results you get.

Comment: @scanny: edited the question itself to reflect only one. the code is the same. There is no output for the left frame.

Comment: Check to see what type the other shapes are. Right after the `for shape in slide.shapes:` add the line `print(shape.shape_type)`. I have an idea you'll find they are group shapes, which are unfortunately not supported in `python-pptx` yet.

Comment: @scanny This is what I get:                                                                                                TEXT_BOX (17)
None
AUTO_SHAPE (1)
AUTO_SHAPE (1)
None
AUTO_SHAPE (1)
AUTO_SHAPE (1)
None
None . So I assume None is a grouped shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shapes that are reporting `None` as their shape type are Group shapes. You can confirm this by printing out their XML:

```
print(shape._element)  # should give something like 'CT_GroupShape'
print(shape._element.xml)  # should show XML that starts with `<p:grpSp>`
```

<s>Group shapes aren't yet supported in `python-pptx`. If you can ungroup them in PowerPoint their text will be accessible.</s>

**UPDATE:** A group shape has no text. However, you can use `group_shape.shapes` to iterate over the shapes inside the group and access their text. Note that groups can contain other groups.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sadly, I've to fall back on OPENXML SDK to pull the text in .NET.